# Python in function mit String

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to program the Spang Hangman.
For this I use the "in" function to check whether the incoming letter is present in the searched word.
E.g .:

```
wort = "affe"
eingaben = "fafe"
```

Is there a possibility with this function to check whether all letters entered in the string correspond to all letters in the string word?
In this example, the two strings would not be the same

```
if eingaben in wort:
    print("Du hast es geschafft")
else:
    print("Rate weiter")
```

Hope the question wasn't too messy ;-)

Comment: Please post your question in English. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, wait a minute

Comment: @AnnZen Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297673/5958455

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can use the `all()` method to ch
eck if all the letters in `eingaben` are also in `wort`:

```
wort = "affe"
eingaben = "fafe"

if all([i in [a for a in wort] for i in eingaben]):
    print("Du hast es geschafft")
else:
    print("Rate weiter")
```

Output:

```
Du hast es geschafft
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply sort each string and see if one is in the other.

```
wort = "affe"
eingaben = "fafe"

a =''.join(sorted(eingaben)) in ''.join(sorted(wort))

print(a)
```

Output :

```
True
```